# Angular2, child properties and elvis operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-http

So i have a complex date model coming from the server to feed my Angular2 component. Following shows a small part of the template for this component:

```
<div>
    <span>{{Person.Address.City}}</span>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Person.Address.City" />
</div>
```

The `Address` might be `null` or `undefined` depending on the data that's returned from the server. I know that elvis operator will save me from one error:

```
<span>{{Person?.Address?.City}}</span>
```

but unfortuantely it won't save me for `[(ngModel)]="Person.Address.City"` as there is no elvis defined for that. You'll get a parser error if you do something like `[(ngModel)]="Person?.Address?.City"` and if you don't then you'll get the `null` exception.

Here are two simplest variation of data, although there can be a lot more:

```
{
    Name:'sam',
    LastName: 'jones',
    Address: {
        Street: '123 somewhere',
        City: 'some land'
        State: 'SL'
    }
}
```

or...

```
{
    Name:'sam',
    LastName: 'jones'
}
```

Since the responsibility of handling these scenarios should be on Angular2 rather than the server that provides the data, due to separation of presentation and business logic, how would I handle the scenario(s)?

Comment: What if you added the needed structure as the data came in?  In other words, would it be sufficient to loop through each object and add an empty Address object with an empty City property if there isn't one already present?  I'm not sure if that is the responsibility of the service itself, but it doesn't seem like a horrible thing to do

Comment: @JakeSmith it's possible to do that in Angular2 as data came in or on the service that provides data. Both of which seem rather hacky to me due to the fact that elvis shouldn't be there or should be there for both scenarios. I rather think having `[(ngModel)]="Person?.Address?.City"` auto-generated once user types inside the textbox is a neat feature. Also to mention, there are more variations and i can't really do nested looping for each of them.

Comment: As I see it, it doesn't really make sense to two-way bind to something that may not exist.  If you want to use two-way binding, I think you need to force the existence of an Address object with a city property.  Since you are calling an external service, your requirement of always needing an Address/City in the model of the component should be enforced on your app.  The API you are calling doesn't have the same requirements as your app does.  If this was an internal API call, then it would be the APIs responsibility to always provide objects who have Address/City properties.

Comment: So in this scenario, Angular2 or my presentation is dictating my business logic? why is it have to be like that? Also, you're enforcing existence by two-way binding to `City` and its parent links. I rather state "don't two-way bind if you don't want it" instead of "force existence if you want two-way binding".

Comment: Your app's requirements 
are dictating your business logic.  Two-way binding carries with it assumptions about the existence of what you are binding to.  I could be wrong, but I don't think two-way binding was intended to be smart enough to just work whether you give it what it needs or not.  The key point here is that the two-way binding is happening with a model in your application, not the "schema" of some external API.  The consistency of your app's data model is what two-way binding is relying on here.  The API you are using knows nothing about two-way binding and doesn't care.

Comment: From the, albeit unfinished, documentation for `ngModel`: "CLASS DESCRIPTION: Binds a domain model to a form control."  Here is the  [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgModel-directive.html).  What you are getting back from your service is not automatically your domain model.  You are lucky if a service that calls an external API gives you the data in the same structure/format as your domain model, and in this case, you were not lucky.  `ngModel` is meant to bind to a domain model, which is referring to the domain of your component/application, and this assumes the existence.

Comment: damn, hard life. Either loop and make sure every complex object is initialized or maintain 3 models and merge two of them inside the component. One model for ASP.NET MVC, another for DB and yet one for Angular2. The one for Angular2 could have a pre-initialized objects, which then is merged with ASP.NET MVC model that's returned by a service.

Comment: Yea it does seem a little unnecessary.  I agree with you there.  But ideally, your DB model, your ASP.NET MVC model, and your front-end Angular 2 domain model shouldn't differ at all.  Really, your service is the only one returning you something different.  Everything else should be domain driven.  If I were you, I would add the Address/City properties on the objects that need it right after you get the data right inside your service.  That way, no other part of your application needs to know that the service is complicating things.  Only the service knows that conversion took place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, you either maintain 3 models, one for front-end (Angular2), one for middle tier (ASP.NET, JAVA, etc...) and another for your data model. Or you could make sure, as i did, that your middle-tier model will not have a null complex object. This means initializing complex properties inside your model and getting away with 2 models.

Also to note, if you have don't or can't modify your middle-tier model, then your only option is to create a compatible model for your front-end (Angular2) and merge as necessary once data has returned from API, service, etc..

Answer (score 0):

At the service level you can add a blank object for Address. Right after receiving a response. 
This way you fix the problem at it's source for entire application.

Here is simple solution with RxJS:

```
this._http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map(res => {
        if (res.Address === null || res.Address === undefined) {
            res.Address = {}
        }
        return object;
    });
```

You might also want to consider removing the Address object if it is blank, right before saving it.